# install (or just use) gimp without sudo privilegies

Tags: sudo, gimp

I need to use gimp in a server, but I don't have administrative privileges. I was wondering if there's a way of executing gimp from a file.

Comment: Since it's [about Red Hat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053567/install-or-just-use-gimp-without-sudo-privilegies#comment1722173_1053570), it's off-topic here.

Comment: Unless you are using some very specialized filter, you can very likely replace Gimp by a more suitable command line tool like ImageMagick. What are you using Gimp for?

Comment: Add letters, crop and merge images basically.

Comment: So really a job for [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (as a command line thing or using the bindings for your language (PHP, Python, Java...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download an [appimage of gimp](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1231847/). An appimage contains the full applications and its dependencies, and can be executed on any linux distribution by making the downloaded file executable and running it. No root permissions are needed in an of these steps.

Comment: I have downloaded the appimage, unzip, and execute ./AppRun-gimp but it seems that I miss something.

Comment: @heracho An appimage is run directly. Make the file executable and execute it by double-clicking on it in the filemanager or with the terminal command ./gimp-git-2.10.3-20180621.glibc2.15-x86_64.AppImage

Comment: totally forgotten that it's possible to run app-images!

Comment: fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied
Could not mount AppImage

Comment: Make sure you `chmod` the file to something like `755`. Then you can double-click to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it the following way

```
apt download gimp
```

For the gimp.deb take the exact name you got from `ls gimp*`command:

```
mkdir ~/gimp
dpkg -x gimp*.deb ~/gimp
```

Comment: Installing through snap requires administrative privileges. The user asked to install/run gimp without administrative privileges.

Comment: With the instructions you currently provide, it will work indeed to install and run without root privileges!

Comment: My shame to post this question in askubuntu, but the server actually run on RedHat and there's no dpkg available.

Comment: Take the solution of vanadium! And download the appimage. Right click an allow to be executable and run it. That's it!